# javascript slide box for image slides

Tags: php, javascript, slide

I am working on this website [[http://ibm-uet.edu.pk/index.php]](http://ibm-uet.edu.pk/index.php).

The image slider used here is a javascript plugin. The problem here is that on the first load up of the page, all the images in the slider are shown in a line, making the page look awkward,..
Please any one, who can tell me to get rid of this bug.

Answer (score 0):

update some css and javascript. First make slider div hidden and when page will ready it will show before calling jQuery slider function.

```
<style>
#coin{
display:none;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#coin').css('display','block');
$('#coin').coinslider({ width: 900, navigation: false, delay: 5000,hoverPause: true });
}); 
</script>
```

Hope this will help.